# Scala - pattern matching with conditional statements?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to do something like:

```
def foo(x: Int): Boolean = {
    case x > 1 => true
    case x < 1 => false
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
def foo(x: Int): Boolean = 
    x match {
        case _ if x > 1 => true
        case _ if x < 1 => false
    }
```

Note that you don't have a case for x == 1 though...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah forget the actual test, it was more about syntax issues.

Comment: You'd probably want to include 1 values in the true category: `case _ if x >= 1`

Comment: just a little question. so in scala, if a case not return value (for example condition not true), scala will continue to run following case branches right ?

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like this:

```
def foo(x: Int) = if (x > 1) true
                  else if (x < 1) false
                  else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Got " + x)
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions is mostly considered bad practice in Scala. Better return `Either[IllegalArgumentException, Boolean]`.

Comment: What? Why? By whose standard is this bad practice? https://github.com/spray/spray/search?p=6&q=throw&ref=cmdform

Answer (score 0):

Since the case of `x == 1` is missing in your example, I assume that it is handled just the same as `x < 1`.

You can do it like this:

```
def foo(x:Int):Boolean = (x - 1).signum match {
  case 1 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

But then, this can of course be simplified a lot:

```
def foo(x:Int) = (x - 1).signum == 1
```

Comment: Um, `def foo(x: Int) = x > 1` would be way simpler and infinitely more clear.